# Animate replacement of one framelayout with two

Tags: android, android-animation, android-framelayout

I have three framelayouts as shown in the code below. Initially, only one framelayout is to be shown and after clicking an item in it, it should exit slide down and two other framelayouts are supposed to slide up from the bottom of the screen.

Replacing one framelayout with another is what we all do, but this sounds a bit trivial.

Please help, how to implement this along with animations(slide up and slide down).
I am talking about framelayouts with ids: primaryMenu, secondaryMenu and tertiaryMenu.

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@color/primaryDark"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/control_area"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_container"
    android:background="@color/primaryDark">

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.StickerView
        android:id="@+id/sticker_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.CropImageView
        android:id="@+id/crop_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.RotateImageView
        android:id="@+id/rotate_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.TextStickerView
        android:id="@+id/text_sticker_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <org.ArtIQ.rex.editor.view.CustomPaintView
        android:id="@+id/custom_paint_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_3"
    android:id="@+id/control_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tertiaryMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondaryMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/primaryMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should handle it in your main activity

Comment: Thats what I m asking...how exactly in main activity?

Comment: whats your root layout?

Comment: I will try to create a test project for this. I think I know how to do it, give me 10-20 mins.